# same activity different listview

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I've been looking for a solution and can't find it so here I am.

Right now what I'm trying to achieve is when I click on an menu option I want to start the same activity with the same menu but with different listview data. The data is from SQLITE.

What I have done is when I select and option (onoptionsitemselected) I pass some arguments to know which data retrieve from database, but it just work the first option, the other ones dosen't work.

This is the code of my activity I think I'm using wrong the Intents

```
public class PlantillaChina extends ActionBarActivity{

 // DB Class to perform DB related operations
DBController controller = new DBController(this);
// Progress Dialog Object
ProgressDialog prgDialog;
HashMap<String, String> queryValues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista);
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    Intent myIntent2 = getIntent();
    Intent myIntent3 = getIntent();
    Intent myIntent4 = getIntent();

    String value = myIntent.getStringExtra("entremeses");
    String value2 = myIntent2.getStringExtra("arroces");
    String value3 = myIntent3.getStringExtra("mar");
    String value4 = myIntent4.getStringExtra("carnes");

 // Get plato records from SQLite DB

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> platoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    if (value.equals("entremeses")){
        platoList = controller.getAllEntremeses();
    }else if(value2.equals("arroces")){
            platoList = controller.getAllArrocesyPasta();
        }else if(value3.equals("mar")){
                platoList = controller.getAllMar();
             }else if(value4.equals("carnes")){      
                        platoList = controller.getAllCarnes();
             }
    // If plato exists in SQLite DB
    if (platoList.size() != 0) {
        // Set the plato Array list in ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(PlantillaChina.this, platoList, R.layout.itemlista, new String[] {
                        "platoNombre", "platoDescripcion", "platoPrecio" }, new int[] { R.id.nombre, R.id.descripcion, R.id.precio });
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaplatos);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.china, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
//    int id = item.getItemId();
  //  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    //    return true;
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.entremeses:
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(this,PlantillaChina.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("entremeses", "entremeses");
        this.startActivity(myIntent);
        break;
    case R.id.arrocesypasta:
        Intent myIntent2=new Intent(this,PlantillaChina.class);
        myIntent2.putExtra("arroces", "arroces");
        this.startActivity(myIntent2);
        break;
    case R.id.pescados:
        Intent myIntent3=new Intent(this,PlantillaChina.class);
        myIntent3.putExtra("mar", "mar");
        this.startActivity(myIntent3);
        break;
    case R.id.carnes:
        Intent myIntent4=new Intent(this,PlantillaChina.class);
        myIntent4.putExtra("carnes", "carnes");
        this.startActivity(myIntent4);
        break;

   } 


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Thanks and Kind Regards

Comment: hi you have option for visibility on and off.Just you put same both listview in same postion and first time visibility gone of second lv.when second time you need other one you visible second one first one gone, Simple and best idea thanks

Comment: use notifydatasetchanged() method instead of calling same activity more then one time. pass appropriate argument to your adapter data and just update your listview on onOptionsItemSelected method instead of calling same activity

Comment: do exactly as @mcd said, that's your solution

Comment: Hi guys. After trying the answer Göktay Kaykusuz gave it worked, but after reading you guys I've tried to do it as you said. But with no luck.

I've changed ListAdapter to BaseAdapter and after the lane myList.Adapter(adapter) I added adapter.notifydatasetchanged().

Also I added a in every onoptionsitemsselected() the lane (different functions)
platoList = controller.getAllEntremeses(); and giving to the adapter this data.

I have some mess somewhere but don't know where

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something got stuck in my head, and i assume it is the cause of your problem. `getStringExtra()` and `putExtra()` methods use key value pairs and your if-else statement have a weird structure. Why don't we try it like down below?

```
public class PlantillaChina extends ActionBarActivity{

 // DB Class to perform DB related operations
DBController controller = new DBController(this);
// Progress Dialog Object
ProgressDialog prgDialog;
HashMap<String, String> queryValues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    String value = myIntent.getStringExtra("key");

 // Get plato records from SQLite DB

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> platoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    if (value.equals("entremeses")){
        platoList = controller.getAllEntremeses();
    }else if(value.equals("arroces")){
            platoList = controller.getAllArrocesyPasta();
        }else if(value.equals("mar")){
                platoList = controller.getAllMar();
             }else if(value.equals("carnes")){      
                        platoList = controller.getAllCarnes();
             }
    // If plato exists in SQLite DB
    if (platoList.size() != 0) {
        // Set the plato Array list in ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(PlantillaChina.this, platoList, R.layout.itemlista, new String[] {
                        "platoNombre", "platoDescripcion", "platoPrecio" }, new int[] { R.id.nombre, R.id.descripcion, R.id.precio });
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaplatos);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.china, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
//    int id = item.getItemId();
  //  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    //    return true;
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.entremeses:
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(this,PlantillaChina.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("key", "entremeses");
        this.startActivity(myIntent);
        break;
    case R.id.arrocesypasta:
        Intent myIntent2=new Intent(this,PlantillaChina.class);
        myIntent2.putExtra("key", "arroces");
        this.startActivity(myIntent2);
        break;
    case R.id.pescados:
        Intent myIntent3=new Intent(this,PlantillaChina.class);
        myIntent3.putExtra("key", "mar");
        this.startActivity(myIntent3);
        break;
    case R.id.carnes:
        Intent myIntent4=new Intent(this,PlantillaChina.class);
        myIntent4.putExtra("key", "carnes");
        this.startActivity(myIntent4);
        break;

   } 


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i'm glad I was able to help.

This one is a rare case i assume. I think the source of your problem is the instance that holds your key-value pairs. Since you refer the same activity, the instance does not get destroyed. Something like down below might be happening if you would choose option 2 after option 1.

entremeses - entremeses
arroces - arroces
mar - null
carnes - null

Instead of:



entremeses - null
arroces - arroces
mar - null
carnes - null

And since you check different keys with each if statement, first option always returns true.